# Content-Security-Policy Spring Security

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, content-security-policy

assuming a working hello world example of spring security and spring mvc.

when i take a trace with wireshark i see the following flags on the http request

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff 
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block 
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate 
Pragma: no-cache 
Expires: 0 
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains 
X-Frame-Options: DENY 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
```

i would like to add this to my headers:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'
```

I know that the X-Frame-Options is doing almost the same job, but still it makes me sleep better.
Now i guess that i would need to do it under the configure function of my spring security configuration however i do not know how exactly, i.e. i suppose 
.headers().something.something(self)

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
//          .csrf().disable()
//          .headers().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(   "/register",
                                "/static/**",
                                "/h2/**",
                                "/resources/**",
                            "/resources/static/css/**", 
                                "/resources/static/img/**" , 
                                "/resources/static/js/**", 
                                "/resources/static/pdf/**"                              
                                ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simply use the addHeaderWriter method like this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      // ...
      .headers()
        .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-Content-Security-Policy","script-src 'self'"))
      // ...
  }
}
```

Note that as soon as you specify any headers that should be included, then only those headers will be include.

To include the default headers you can do:

```
http
  .headers()
    .contentTypeOptions()
    .xssProtection()
    .cacheControl()
    .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
    .frameOptions()
    .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-Content-Security-Policy","script-src 'self'"))
    // ...
```

You can refer to the [spring security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-custom).

Comment: works like a charm , Christophe thank you. One thing that i have noted is that  chromium / rekonq / opera do display the css when the page is loaded, but firefox does not display the css when  the ".addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeaderWriter("X-Content-Security-Policy","script-src 'self'"))" is enabled. Also note the missing "s" in the name of the method "StaticHeaderWriter" i.e. "StaticHeadersWriter". I have seen that this is also the case with the referece documentation that you posted.

Comment: ok i found why this was  not working in firefox.  i needed to use bought headers "X-Content-Security-Polic" and "Content-Security-Policy" transition explanation here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Using_Content_Security_Policy

Comment: Update to anyone reading this. If the code at the bottom doesn't run you need to add ".and()" to the end of each line 

E.g. .contentTypeOptions()..and()
.xssProtection().and()

Comment: You may also be able to do 
".headers(headers -> headers.contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'"))"
Instead of resetting the defaults (see the link provided by OP.

Answer (score 35):

While the approach with `StaticHeadersWriter` works, in the newest versions of Spring Security it's possible to use a special method:

```
headers()
    .contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'");
```

See documentation for details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/headers.html#headers-csp-configure

Answer (score 8):

As documented in Spring security documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    // ...
    .headers()
        .contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self' https://trustedscripts.example.com; object-src https://trustedplugins.example.com; report-uri /csp-report-endpoint/")
        .reportOnly();
}
}
```